# Codewars challenge - Longest vowel substring

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Right, i am going through a code Wars challenge the aim of which is to return the length of the longest vowel substring, as in "codewarriors" would be "io" so the answer would be 2. The way i have solved it is by replacing the non vowels with space, splitting the vowels left over in to an array and then looping over this array and pushing the first substring into another array, I then set up another for loop so i could loop over the values of the first array check the lengths with the second array and replace with the longest if necessary.

This is where i ran into trouble, as i am pushing the first value (the one to compare with the others), but if in the second loop it needs to be replaced i am just replacing the value not pushing, so if the first value is the longest the array will be an object, if it needs to be replaced in the second loop it will be replaced but it will turn in to a string, this means that the ending return statement giving the length would need to change between longest.length & longest[0].length, i got around it by adding a conditional checking the typeof at the end, but im wondering if there is another way around it?

I am a beginner so forgive me if the above is a bit confusing, and any tips on other ways to solve the challenge are very welcome.

This is the code that doesn't work -

```
  function longestVowel(str) {

  var seperateVowels = str.replace(/[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]/ig, ' ');

  var split = seperateVowels.split(" ");

  var longest = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    if(longest.length === 0 && split[i] != "") {
      longest = split[i];
    }  for(var j = 0; j < longest.length; j++) {
      if(split[i].length > longest[j].length) {
        longest = split[i];
      }
     }
    }

  return longest.length;

}
```

And here is my work around -

```
function longestVowel(str) {

  var seperateVowels = str.replace(/[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]/ig, ' ');

  var split = seperateVowels.split(" ");

  var longest = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    if(longest.length === 0 && split[i] != "") {
      longest.push(split[i]);
    }  for(var j = 0; j < longest.length; j++) {
      if(split[i].length > longest[j].length) {
        longest = split[i];
      }
     }
    }

  if(typeof longest == "object") {
    return longest[0].length;
  } else {
    return longest.length;
  }

}

longestVowel("suoidea");
```

Comment: @Vasan: You forgot to mention that you need to keep track of the highest counter-value you have seen during the traverse.

Comment: If all you want is the length, why not just start a counter at first position and traverse the string, resetting the counter if you see a non-vowel? Before resetting, store the counter in a `max` variable if your current counter value is more than current max. Thanks @MrSmith42

Comment: Very helpful, thanks Vasan this is a much better way of doing things!

Answer (score 1):

I like your approach of filtering out non-vowels at first and then splitting it into an array.

**Edit:** Modified answer thanks to the suggestions in the comments:

```
function longestVowel(str) {
  let separateVowels = str.replace(/[^aeiou]/ig, ' ').split(' ');
  let longest;

  separateVowels.forEach(function(vowelGroup) {
    longest = vowelGroup.length > longest.length
      ? vowelGroup
      : longest;
  });

  return longest;
}

console.log(longestVowel('suoidea')); // uoi
```

Or with [JavaScript 1.8/EcmaScript5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
function longestVowel(str) {
  let separateVowels = str.replace(/[^aeiou]/ig, ' ').split(' ');
  let longest = separateVowels.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.length > b.length ? a : b;
  });

  return longest;
}
```

**Original answer**:
The way I'd solve this from there is to sort the array by length and just get the first (therefore longest) item:

```
function longestVowel(str) {
  let separateVowels = str.replace(/[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]/ig, ' ').split(' ');
  let longest = separateVowels.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b.length - a.length;
  })[0];

  return longest;
}

console.log(longestVowel('suoidea')); // uoi
```

Comment: I think the regex could be shortened as `/[^aeiou]/ig`. Also, sorting is `O(n log n)`, while finding the max can be done in linear time `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind a linear algorithm `O(n)` here is that you really have to look at the each element of the array only once.

At each step of the iteration we maintain two variables `globalMax` and `currentMax` which hold the longest vowel substring so far and the longest vowel substring currently being considered respectively.

When an vowel is encountered we check starting from there how long can we go until we come across an non vowel character. That is untill the point at which it will not be a vowel substring anymore. This will be the `currentMax` which we compare with the `globalMax` to check if we have encountered a longer vowel substring. So, `globalMax` is the best of all `currentMax`'s

Suppose the input was 'suoideaoi'

```
  i    |  s[i]  | currentMax  | globalMax
-------|--------|-------------|-----------
  0    |    s   |      0      |   0
  1    |    u   |      0      |   0
  2    |    o   |      1      |   1
  3    |    i   |      2      |   2
  4    |    d   |      0      |   2
  5    |    e   |      1      |   2  
  6    |    a   |      2      |   2
  7    |    o   |      3      |   3
  8    |    i   |      4      |   4
```

Here' we count form `i = 2 to 3` as they are vowel's but at `i = 3` we notice that the substring is no longer a vowel substring anymore so we stop there and reset the `currentMax` to 0.

What makes this a `O(n)` is that once we have checked for the vowel substring `s[2] to s[3]` i.e) `oi` we can be sure that this vowel substring need not be considered further in any of the vowel substring that may come later as there is a non vowel character after this thus making any substring includes this substring to not be a vowel substring.